# AngularJS load data on demand with load more functionality

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to AngularJS. I want to create a table with the user's name in every row. Once the user clicks any one of the users, it should fetch the data from server and load the details below that user. If he clicks another user, it should clear previous user's data and populate the details of the selected user. I have created a table and json for the above requirement and it is coming fine. I do not know 1) how to append the details under the current user by clicking the load more button 2) how to remove the details under the previous and load the details of the current user. I have attached the output and code below.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat-start="val in data.Titles" class="h">
        <td colspan="2" ng-hide="val.title == undefined">{{val.title}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="con in val.details">
        <td>{{con.portfolio}}</td>
        <td>{{con.status}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td colspan="2">Load More</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

-->
**Code:**

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

        $scope.data = {"Titles":[{title:"User 1",    
            details: [{portfolio: "Microsoft", status:"Male"},{portfolio:"IBM", status:"Female"}]
    }, {title:"User 2",
        details: [{portfolio: "Yahoo", status:"Male"},{portfolio: "Google", status:"Female"}]
    }]};
```

}]);

Comment: This json does not make much sense to me. How can User 1 be Male and Female at the same time? If you plan to get data from the server you want to include some id fields for each user. What exactly are the 'details' that should be loaded when clicking on 'Load more'?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for that. The status are Active and Inactive.